# "pattern-match" operator ~= causes "Binary operator '~=' cannot be operand" error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying out Swift new operator `~=` but ran into a weird error.

`var filteredNumbers1 = [20,30,50,15].filter({15...30 ~= $0})`

Works as expected.

`var filteredNumbers2 = [20,30,50,15].filter({$0 ~= 15...30})`

Throws error

> Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'Range < Int >'

I am wondering what is the difference between `15...30 ~= $0` and `$0 ~= 15...30` ?

Comment: There is nothing "new" about `~=`.

Comment: You might want to consider using `(15...30).contains($0)` as a more readable version of your `filter` condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~=` in the Swift standard library is defined to expect the pattern on the left and the value on the right. The declaration is:

```
public func ~=<I : ForwardIndexType where I : Comparable>(pattern: Range<I>, value: I) -> Bool
```

You could add your own version which supports value on the left and range on the right if you like with something like:

```
func ~=<I : ForwardIndexType where I : Comparable>(value: I, pattern: Range<I>) -> Bool {
    return pattern ~= value
}
```

Comment: You should note that this could have unintended side effects... for example now you're able to `switch` over ranges with `Int` cases, which is a bit weird.